# Sails.js query runs at end of function

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

I am working on a project in which I have to store multiple stops, one route and their relation in 3 different tables. I am successfully storing stops and the route. but to store the relation I need to get the id's(auto generated primary key)of the recently stored route and all the recently stored stops. I am getting them by running the query to find max id which is the latest stored id. This is my code:

```
create: function (req,res,next)
    {

        var stopsArray = req.param('latLngArray');

        var so="";
        var totalBusStops = req.param('totalStops');

        var routeToSave=new OneRoute();
        routeToSave.routeName="This route";
        routeToSave.totalStops=totalBusStops;

        Routes.create(routeToSave, function routeCreated(err, routeToSave){
            if(err) return next(err);
                res.json(routeToSave); 
        });   // creating routes

        for(var i=0;i<stopsArray.length;i++){
            var us = new busStop();
            us.lngPos = stopsArray[i].Lng;
            us.latPos = stopsArray[i].Lat;

            BusStop.create( us ,function stopCreated (err,us)
            { 
                if(err) return next(err);
                res.json(us);   
            });  // creating bus stops#
        }

        var currentRouteId = "";
        Routes.query("select max(routeId) from routes",  function(err, results) {
            if(err){ res.json({ error: err.message }, 400);}
            else{
                currentRouteId = results[0]['max(routeId)'];
                console.log("route ID: "+results[0]['max(routeId)']);
            }
        });   // max riute ID

        var relation= new routeStopR();
        relation.routeId=currentRouteId;
        var currentStopId = "";

        BusStop.query("select max(stopId) from busstop",  function(err, results) {
            if(err){res.json({ error: err.message }, 400);}
            else{

                currentStopId = results[0]['max(stopId)'];
                console.log("Bus Stop ID: "+currentStopId);
            }
        });

        relation.stopId=currentStopId;

        console.log("");
        console.log("relation Route: "+relation.routeId);
        console.log("relation Stop: "+relation.stopId);


        RouteStops.create(relation,function relationCreated (err,relation)
        {
            if(err) return next(err);
            res.json(relation);
        });

    }
```

The problem I am facing is that the get queries are running at the end of the function no matter where I place them in the function. Due to this I am not able to use the id's I get from the queries. Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

One more problem I am facing is that the query which gets `max(stopId)` from `busstop` table returns value from old data. And sometimes the `max(routeID)` from `routes` also have this problem.

Kindly help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is a very common case of not knowing how to use async functions in Node.js. Your queries are asynchronous, meaning node goes off to run those queries and continues executing the rest of your code on your page. But the rest of the code on your page is dependent on the values found in your queries. A common solution is to use a library like async

https://www.npmjs.org/package/async

I would read through these to learn more

http://nodeschool.io/#learnyounode

http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2013/06/think-async/